# Matplotlib plt.xlim([x_min,x_max]), list object not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot a scatterplot, but set the x-label limits.

```
axScatter = plt.subplot(111)
axScatter.scatter(x=mean_var_r["Variance"],y=mean_var_r["Mean"])
xlim = [-0.003, 0.003]
plt.xlim(xlim)
plt.show()
```

For some reason, I get the error, that the list object is not callable. I am well aware, that the question was asked before here: [list not callable for plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612405/list-not-callable-for-plot), but unfortunately, the solution does not work for me. Is there another way?

Thanks and happy coding

Comment: The code you have shown will not produce that error. It is likely that you have done `plt.xlim = [-0.003, 0.003]`. If this is not the case please create a [mcve]

Comment: I have tried, to test the code in a new environment. Unfortunately it does not work. I use the current version of matplotlib 3.0.3.

Comment: Can you please paste the stack trace? That way it will be clearer where the error is being raised

Comment: Sure @lxop:                                                                                                        
```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-127-c2bb5acd7fb9> in <module>
      2 axScatter.scatter(x=mean_var_r["Variance"],y=mean_var_r["Mean"])
      3 xlim = [-0.003, 0.003]
----> 4 plt.xlim(xlim)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable```. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you restart your notebook/editor and directly try `plt.xlim(-0.003, 0.003)`, does it work?

Comment: Agree with @DavidG. The code you posted will not produce that error. If you wrote `plt.xlim = [...]` you overwrote a function with a list (and broke it). It will stay broken while the module is loaded, so you need to restart the notebook/kernel.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from [seaborn](https://pypi.org/project/seaborn/), `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` properties work quite intuitively:

```
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.lineplot(x=range(0,100),
                  y=range(0,100))

ax.set_xlim([50, 100])
ax.set_ylim([50, 100])
```

[image: see resulting plot]

(*Using matplotlib==3.2.2, and seaborn==0.10.1)

Answer (score -3):

It appears that the API has changed. See [this page](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html). The function no longer accepts a list; the function accepts a tuple.

Try this:

```
axScatter = plt.subplot(111)
axScatter.scatter(x=mean_var_r["Variance"],y=mean_var_r["Mean"])
xlim = (-0.003, 0.003)
plt.xlim(xlim)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The API has changed again, so it does not work anymore