# matplotlib plt.ylim raises error list object not callable

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

First of all, I know that this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56131271/matplotlib-plt-xlimx-min-x-max-list-object-not-callable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612405/list-not-callable-for-plot), but none of those helped me further.

I am trying to set the ylim of my graph. The code of concern is as simple as it gets:

```
plt.scatter(nDat, tDat)

plt.ylim(200, 300)

plt.show()
```

If I run this I get

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Now if I run it with xlim instead of ylim it works perfectly fine and it returns the figure I ask without any problems. It is only when I *literally* change the x to y that this error comes up. Frankly, I am baffled.

Thank you and a good day.

Comment: cannot reproduce the problem, it is not throwinig me an error. could you post the rest of the code the throws the error? maybe your data is faulty or something else is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might have accidentally overwritten `plt.ylim` with a list. This can e.g. happen if you run `plt.ylim = [200, 300]`, which will overwrite the matplotlib method `ylim` with the list.

If you are using a Jupyter Notebook, make sure to restart your kernel to reset this. Otherwise make sure to check your code for such an assignment and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use plt.axes() and then set limits for x and y axis

```
plt.scatter(nDat, tDat)
ax = plt.axes()
# Set ylim
ax.set_ylim(0, 20)
# Set xlim
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
```

Source: [Matplotlib Axes](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axes.html)